# Not able to click on all the links which is been extracted from specific area of webpage extracted

Tags: selenium-webdriver

when i go to bbc.com there in dashboard  we have news,sport,weather,shop ,earth  different link   so when the code run it navigate to first link or screen to do the click operation on next element and then it getting stop i want to click all the links which are news,sport,weather,shop. pls help

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
@Test
public void snapage() throws InterruptedException{
driver.get(" http://www.bbc.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement J= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='orb-header']"));
String one=".//*[@id='orb-nav-links']/ul/li[";
String two="]/a";
Thread.sleep(2000);
for(int i=1;i<=8;i++){
String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath(one+i+two)).getText();
System.out.println(text);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(one+i+two)).click();
```

Comment: what's the issue with your code? you explained your requirement but not the issues you have with the code. please avoid explanations like 'it does not work', add some technical detail about the issues and your attempts.

Comment: sorry this is my 1st post  new to it will make sure from next time . issue is that  when i run code it hit two links then get stop it should click on 8 links .

Comment: no problem. please understand that we are not running the tests so everything you know is unknown to the people on SO: add all the relevant details to the question. the best is a way to reproduce the issue and the link to test it (if possible)

Comment: ok thanks ,  now is it clear are you able to understand what i mean to say ? do u have any solution for this

Comment: Hi, can i have exception what is getting here?

Comment: Exception is :org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='orb-nav-links']/ul/li[3]/a"}

Answer (score 0):

One approach what you can follow here is that, you can extract all the links being shown at a time and then navigate to those one at a time. You can refer to below code snippet:

```
public void clickBanners(){
        bannerLinks = new HashSet<String>();

            List<WebElement> banners = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<xPath_of_links>"));           

            for(WebElement banner : banners){
                bannerLinks.add(banner.getAttribute("href"));
            }

            for(String bannerLink : bannerLinks){
                driver.navigate().to(bannerLink);
                }
        }
```

Do let us know if this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks abhinav for ur suggestion , this approach also work but i  want to know how to resolve the issue which i am facing in my code    : Exception is :org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='orb-nav-links']/ul/li[3]/a"}

Comment: I am not sure but this can be one of the reason that you are building the xpath dynamically and trying to find element as per build xpath but it is not  always that element which you have specified is there on the page being displayed as banner keeps on moving so and forth and hence it would not be able to click. What you can also do is wait for the element to be displayed and clickable and then do the action. Hope this clarifies a bit.